# Merge Pandas Dataframes based on date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking to merge two pandas DataFrames based on date. The issue is the 2nd dataframe does not include every date from the 1st dataframe. I need to use every date from `df1` with the latest value from `df2`.

```
+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| DataFrame 1 |               |             |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| Date        |  Sales loc1   |  Sales loc2 |
| 1/1/17      |  100          |  95         |
| 1/2/17      |  125          |  124        |
| 1/3/17      |  115          |  152        |
| ...         |               |             |
| 2/1/17      |  110          |  111        |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+


+-------------+---------+------+
| DataFrame 2 |         |      |
+-------------+---------+------+
| Date        |  exp    |  loc |
| 1/1/17      |  100    |  1   |
| 1/1/17      |  125    |  2   |
| 2/1/17      |  115    |  1   |
| 2/1/17      |  110    |  2   |
+-------------+---------+------+


+---------------+---------------+--------------+------------+-------------+
| New Dataframe |               |              |            |             |
+---------------+---------------+--------------+------------+-------------+
| Date          |  Sales loc1   |  Sales loc2  |  exp loc1  |  exp loc2   |
| 1/1/17        |  100          |  95          |  100       |  125        |
| 1/2/17        |  125          |  124         |  100       |  125        |
| 1/3/17        |  115          |  152         |  100       |  125        |
| ...           |               |              |            |             |
| 2/1/17        |  110          |  111         |  115       |  110        |
+---------------+---------------+--------------+------------+-------------+
```

The values from df2 will be used for multiple cells till there is a new value in df2.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Are there always 2 sets of values in `df2`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ There is date, identifier(loc in example) and a value for each row

Comment: Yes but will there always be two rows for the same date?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Not always but sometimes there will be repeat dates in df2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generalised solution where there can be any number of rows for the same date in `Date` would involve,

1. First, merging `df1` and `df2` using `merge`
2. Next, using `groupby` + `apply` to flatten the dataframe
3. Finally, a little cleanup to fix the column names using `rename` and `add_prefix`

```
v = df1.merge(df2[['Date', 'exp']])\
       .groupby(df1.columns.tolist())\
       .exp\
       .apply(pd.Series.tolist)

df = pd.DataFrame(v.tolist(), index=v.index)\
       .rename(columns=lambda x: x + 1)\
       .add_prefix('exp loc')\
       .reset_index()

df

     Date  Sales loc1  Sales loc2  exp loc1  exp loc2
0  1/1/17         100          95       100       125
1  2/1/17         110         111       115       110
```

---

Here's another solution that should work nicely if you only have *two* (or, in general, exactly N) sets of rows per `Date` in `df2`.

```
n = 2
v = pd.DataFrame(
     df2.exp.values.reshape(-1, n), 
     index=df2.Date.unique(), 
     columns=range(1, n + 1)
).add_prefix('exp loc')\
 .rename_axis('Date')\
 .reset_index()
```

Now, it's just a simple merge with `df1` on `Date`.

```
df1.merge(v, on='Date')

     Date  Sales loc1  Sales loc2  exp loc1  exp loc2
0  1/1/17         100          95       100       125
1  2/1/17         110         111       115       110
```

Or, as @A. Leistra pointed out, you might want a different sort of result using a *left outer merge*:

```
df1.merge(v, how='left', on='Date').ffill()

     Date  Sales loc1  Sales loc2  exp loc1  exp loc2
0  1/1/17         100          95     100.0     125.0
1  1/2/17         125         124     100.0     125.0
2  1/3/17         115         152     100.0     125.0
3  2/1/17         110         111     115.0     110.0
```

Comment: The reshaping is correct but the OP wants a left join, so instead of the inner join you should have df1.merge(v, how='left', on='date').ffill()

Comment: @A.Leistra I see what you mean. I assumed that was just OP showing output with data that they did not include.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll test this solution when I get home.

Comment: @user3029296 Sure, let me know how it goes.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I wasn't able to use your solution as I kind of oversimplified my question. I had to hack together something that is probably not elegant enough to be posted here. As your solution probably answers the question asked, im going to give you the right answer. Thanks for your help.